# Django api stream csv file and upload to s3 in a thread

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, python-multithreading

I have a Django APIView that generates CSV file stream and returns it using StreamingHttpResponse. I want to upload the generated file to s3 as well in a separate thread as I do not want the response to stall until upload is completed.

I thought of saving the stream in a TemporaryFile object and use that to trigger s3 upload in a separate thread once the stream is complete. On following this approach I cannot use Context Manager as the file is automatically closed when context manager exits. I had to resort to closing the file manually once the upload got completed. I would like to avoid this manual file closing process. How do I solve this?

Here is the view:

```
class CsvExportView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        response = StreamingHttpResponse(
                    streaming_content=get_file_stream(),
                    content_type='text/csv'
                )
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format('some_name')
        return response
```

Here is the `get_file_stream()` method:

```
import threading

from tempfile import TemporaryFile

class TempFileManager(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._file = TemporaryFile()

    def get_file(self, parameter_list):
        pass

    def write_to_file(self, data)
        self._file.write(data)

    def close_file(self):
        self._file.close()

def get_file_stream():
    file_mng = TempFileManager()

    # get_csv_stream method is a generator that yields csv file content
    # by calling external api and complex data processing
    for data in get_csv_stream():

        # keep writing to temp file
        file_mng.write_to_file(data)

        # yield chunks to browser
        yield data

    # once all data is received
    # spawn a thread and do the upload
    # complete request lifecycle
    t = threading.Thread(target=upload_file_to_s3, args=(file_mng, ))
    t.start()

def upload_file_to_s3(self, manager):
    # some code to upload file
    upload(manager.get_file())

    # remember to close file
    manager.close_file()
```

The above approach works fine but seems very cluttered and error-prone. This would be much easier if a context manager is used like this:

```
def get_file_stream():
    with TemporaryFile() as tmp:

        for data in get_csv_stream():
            # keep writing to temp file
            tmp.write(data)
            yield data

        upload_file_to_s3(tmp)
```

But I do not want the user to wait until the file is uploaded to s3 so since threading is involved, the context manager might close the file even before the upload process starts.

Does anyone know a better way to handle this situation?